# Is there anyway where we can style up the options of select2

Tags: javascript, html, css, jquery-select2

I have a select2 plugin working for select boxes.
The options are the results of two values concatenated together.
I need to give different color to one of the values in select2 box.
Are there any options for those ?

**My Html**

```
<select id="template" class="form-control template-select-search" style="display: inline-block; width: 200px;">
    <option value="">-- Template --</option>
    <option value="${article.id}">value1 : value2 </option>
</select>
```

This value2 needs to be modified for styling.Went through lots of articles but couldnt get help.
Thanks for the help in advance

This is the [PLUNKER](https://plnkr.co/edit/rK73fZKT50Mzk7YVQE6R?p=preview) I have created

Comment: You need to stylize the generated content. Plugins like select2 will create boxes and layers to achieve the same functionality as `<select>` element does, but the `<select>` element will be hide.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider did you read the question? He asks for select2 plugin...

Answer (score 2):

This may be a quicky but should work. Do something like

```
<option value="${article.id}">value1 :
    <span style="background-color:Your Color"> value2 </span>
</option>
```

Comment: @QaiserRajput added [plnk](https://plnkr.co/edit/rK73fZKT50Mzk7YVQE6R?p=preview),